# How to make dropdown menu in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I have really tough time with dropdowns in one sequence of project.
Hence, I have two models

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :addresses

end
```

and Address.rb

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

end
```

Then I have checkout process-step one where user inputs his address. There are dropdown menu which should look like this:

***Option 1***: #{current_user.first_name} {current_user.last_name}, {current_user.address}

If User clicks on this option in dropdown menu(default) and then continue Address should be taken from current user and proceed.(this action is authorized)

***Option 2:*** New Address

If User clicks on that option, new form should appear where User can input first_name, last_name and address.

I tried with select and collection select tags but seems it isn't what I need. I know that I can use onChange js method for form, but I don't know how to insert address on Option 1 as a valid argument for my form.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE

```
<%= form.fields_for :address do |form| %>
  <%= form.select_tag "bill address", options_for_select([[Address.where(:user_id => current_spree_user.id).collect{|b| "#{b.firstname} #{b.lastname}: #  {b.address1}, #{b.state}"}, current_user.id], ["New Adress",  ""]] %>
<% end %>
```

I tried with this but got an error Couldn't find Address with 'id'=Nella Nienow: 801 Greenfelder Court, New York(I assigned this address to current_user in console)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know what you mean by that Option 2, you have to be more specific. As per option 1, with what I understood, you want to do a dropdown menu where each row has the username, lastname and address of respective user. If so, you could do something like this:

```
<%= form_with model: @user do |user| %>
<%= user.select :id, list: User.all.collect{|b| ["#{b.username} #{b.lastname}: #{b.address}"]} %>
<% end %>
```

EDIT:
I can see you did make a post about a 'dynamic dropdown menu', and I think I got a better clue of what you are trying to make with Option 2. So basically, you should check the routes on your terminal and make a link_to, which would link to that route.

Type rails routes on your terminal, see the route that creates a new user and use link_to, like:

```
<%= link_to "Link to new form", your_route %>
```

and then you could just do a User.new form and redirect the page to self.

Comment: Actually I don't want in Option#1 to collect all Users but only current(logged in) user.
So dropdown menu should have only 2 options and should look like this: ex:1)Joe Doe, Manhhaten, United States(firstname,lastname and address of Current User)
 2)New Address(I made it through routes as you said and works fine). Thank you very much:)